# Divide a grid into rectangle

Tags: algorithm

I have a grid of 0's and #'s. 
I want to regroup all the 0's into rectangles. What is the minimum number of rectangles needed?

Example :

```
#00#00
#00#00
0000#0
000000

#11#34
#11#34
2222#4
222254
```

In this example we use 5 rectangles. There are other solutions, but 5 rectangles is the minimum to cover all 0's.

Comment: Can you re-arrange the #s and 0s? Or you just want to draw rectangles around them and see the minimum needed?

Comment: I just want to draw rectangles around them and see the minimum needed.

Comment: Can the rectangles overlap? Are you trying to solve this specific instance or any instance? We need more information and what you've tried already to help you.

Comment: Finding the minimal number of rectangles smells NP-Hard, though I have no reduction in mind at the moment.

Comment: They cannot overlap, otherwise the minimum would not be 5. This specific instance is already solved, I want of course to solver any instance, given a grid of size N*M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) and is known as 2D variation of the classic [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), called **2D-binpacking**. 

Thus, **there is no known polynomial solution to the problem**.

This is widely studied, here is an example [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20151216022736/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.98.3502&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that deals with ways to approximate a solution to this problem.

You could also try Genthic Algorithms or other heuristical approaches to solve the problem.